# Reloading data in slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid, golden-layout

Using goldenlayout, and I have a slickgrid loaded inside a container (as the tutorial outlined).

I have a timer that goes out and pulls new data.

I would like to know how to update the data in the slickgrid with the new data.

Question 1) - How do i create a div inside the container and give it a name
Question 2) - How do i do a refresh of content in the container
Question 3) - How do i do a refresh on the container

I guess i need more detail in the question to meet quality standards.

I can create the and load the grid at creation time, as per the examples, now i need to reload and present the new data from the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [examples](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples), particularly 'AJAX-loading Data with Search'?